# Find the equations to the normal lines of a curve where $x = 4$.

Tags: calculus

> Find the equations to the normal lines for the curve defined by
>
> $$y^2+xy-x^2=5$$
>
> In the points where $x=4$.

I'm not entirely sure how to even tackle this kind of problem, but let's see:

When $x=4$, we would have

$$y^2+4y-16=5$$

And we would have two solutions: $y=3$ and $y=-7$, so we need the equations for the normal lines that pass through $(4,3)$ and $(4,-7)$.

So I'm already confused. How come this curve has two images for $x = 4$?
I don't think I even understand what I am being asked.

Comment: Why can't there be two images? All curves need not be functions. All the standard conics are non-functional curves.

Comment: @G-man ah, well, I didn't know that. So this curve is not a function? Does that mean I can't derive it? (I was guessing deriving it would be part of the solution or something like that)

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "derive"?

Comment: @G-man I mean getting the derivative of $y^2+4y-16=5$. I assumed that you could calculate derivatives of functions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *curve* doesn't have to be a *function*, implicitly defined curve is given by relation $$F(x,y)=0$$

Where $z=F$ is a function $F\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. We are *slicing* it by a surface $z=0$:

[image]

Thus, the curve may be multivalued in $Oxy$ plane. And it looks like the following:

[image]

The second thing is a derivative of this curve. When we have some function of one variable $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, its derivative is function of one variable too. But things get complicated when considering a curve $C$ — its derivative is given by

$$G\colon C\to\mathbb R$$

So every point of this curve has its image — the slope of a tangent at this point. In your case slopes at points intersecting with $x=4$ are given by $G(4,3)$ and $G(4,7)$.

Comment: I have calculated the implicit derivative to be $$\frac{2x-y}{2y+x}$$ So the slopes of the tangent lines at $x = 4$ should be obtained by evaluating $x=4$ in this derivative, rather than the original function $y^2+4y-16=5$, no? If I plug $x=4$ in this derivative, I would get that $y=0$.

Comment: You've calculated that $$G(x,y)=\frac{2x-y}{2y+x}$$ Now to find the slope at $(4,3)$, you calculate $$G(4,3)=\frac{2\cdot 4-3}{2\cdot 3+4}=\frac{5}{10}$$

Comment: I see. $\frac{5}{10}$ would be the slope for a tangent line that passes by $(4,3)$. The tangent line equation would be

$$y-3=\frac{5}{10}(x-4)$$

Which is

$$y=\frac{x}{2}+1$$

It concerns me, because apparently the answer should be

$$y=-2x+11$$

According to my book.

Comment: That's because you have to calculate equation of _normal_ line. As you probably know, the normal line is perpendicular to the tangent line, thus the slope is inversed and negated: $$\text{slope of normal}=-\frac{1}{\text{slope of tangent}}$$

Comment: See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3yuv7onwho

Comment: Oh! Right! The normal line. I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are given an implicitly defined curve $F(x,y)=0$ and found points $(x_0,y_0)$ on this curve. The tangent at these points is defined by implicit differentiation
$$
∂_xF(x_0,y_0)·(x-x_0)+∂_yF(x_0,y_0)·(y-y_0)=0
$$
which also tells you the direction of the normal to the tangent and thus to the curve.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

See, there are two tangent lines for the circle at $x=0$.